# Does this excerpt from a textbook describes the Present Indefinite in case of performatives?

Tags: present-tense

The examples are from the book "A Grammar of Present-day English" by I. Krylova and E. Gordon.

"I **repeat**, the girl has been extremely impertinent," he said.

You **leave** me no choice.

I **swear** it to you!

I **refuse** to listen to you. You **talk** such nonsense.

"Where shall we have our meal?" "Anywhere you like". "I **choose** the kitchen then."

"You've always treated me badly and now you **insult** me," Maurice shouted in his turn.

My dear, how you **throw** about your money!

She said: "How swiftly the years **fly**!".

"May I help you to wash the baby?" "It is very kind of you. Ah, how he **kicks**! Hs he splashed you?"

Why **do** you **talk** like that to me?

In this textbook it is just said that the speaker just names the occurrence itself, the action as such.
And a comment: the Present Indefinite is also used for an instantaneous action which takes place at the moment of speaking but it is not viewed in its progress.

Screenshot from the the book by Krylova and Gordon:
[image]

Screenshot from the book Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewings:

[image]

Could you tell me whether these are all performative verbs (in bold)?
And are these two excerpts from the two textbooks describe the same phenomenon?

Comment: I'd be very wary of any book that claims there is a 'present indefinite tense'.

Comment: @BillJ I did not find the term "tense" used anywhere in the question, nor in the screenshots. As far as Wikipedia is concerned, ["present indeterminative"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present) is just another label for "simple present" and "present simple"

Comment: By 'present indefinite' we understand 'present indefinite tense'. The book talks of 'present indefinite' under the heading of tenses. Most grammars and usage guides call it simply the 'present tense' (or sometimes the 'simple present tense').